# Flare (particle system) showing weird semi-transparent rectangles instead of smoke when there's fog in the scene

Tags: unity, rendering, particles, fog

I'm making an FPS game with some fog in the scene.

I've added a flare particle system (from the standard assets' prefabs) but it looks like it has some weird collision with the fog.

Whenever the fog is enabled I get these weird rectangles on top of the flare like in this screenshot:

[image: flare rectangles]

I've noticed that when I turn off the fog they disappear, also I've noticed that when I turn off the *Emission* part of the particle system the rectangles disappear, but of course, also most of the wanted effect is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It appears that the standard asset of "ParticleFlare" was causing the problems!**

Maybe the black texture around it is not 100% black or it has some transparency. I'm not sure exactly, but it's definitely the culprit.

When I changed the texture on the shader component to (mostly) anything else - the glitch was gone!

Here is where you set it:

[image: settings changed]

(I chose a texture called "VignetteMask" which worked for me, just had to make the particles size a bit smaller)

And this is the result:

[image: result of changing the texture]